# How to get ID on the fly with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a question for you to upgrade my knowledge.

I am trying to create an inline editing page, the data are stored in a database.
In the table "content" I create 2 fields for testing purpose, the "id" and the "text" field.

If I want to modify the field with the "id=25" or id=X, I know how to do it manually, just specify in the MySQL Query "WHERE id=25", but if I have a list of 1000 entries, how can I modify the query to get the ID on the fly?

Here is the code, I am playing on:

**index.php** file

```
<style>
body {      
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color:#333333;
    font-size:13px;
}

h1{
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-size: 28px;        
}

a{
    color: #0071D8;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#wrap{
    width: 500px;
    margin:0 auto;              
    overflow:auto;      
}

#content{
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#editable {     
    padding: 10px;      
}

#status{
    display:none; 
    margin-bottom:15px; 
    padding:5px 10px; 
    border-radius:5px;
}

.success{
    background: #B6D96C;
}

.error{
    background: #ffc5cf; 
}

#footer{
    margin-top:15px;
    text-align: center;
}

#save{  
    display: none;
    margin: 5px 10px 10px;      
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;    
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;    
    padding: 5px 10px;  
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    color: #606060;
    border: solid 1px #b7b7b7;  
    background: #fff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#ededed));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #ededed);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed');
}   

#save:hover
{
    background: #ededed;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#dcdcdc));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #dcdcdc);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dcdcdc');
}

</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

$("#save").click(function (e) {         
    var content = $('#editable').html();    

    $.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
        content: content
        },              
        success:function (data) {

            if (data == '1')
            {
                $("#status")
                .addClass("success")
                .html("Data saved successfully")
                .fadeIn('fast')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow');   
            }
            else
            {
                $("#status")
                .addClass("error")
                .html("An error occured, the data could not be saved")
                .fadeIn('fast')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow');   
            }
        }
    });   

});

$("#editable").click(function (e) {
    $("#save").show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $("#save").hide();  
});

 });
 </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="status"></div>

    <div id="content">

    <div id="editable" contentEditable="true">
    <?php
        //get data from database.
        include("db.php");
        $sql = mysql_query("select * from content");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);     
        echo $row['id'];
        echo "<br />";
        echo $row['text'];
    ?>      
    </div>  

    <button id="save">Save</button>
    </div>

</div>
  </body>
```

And here is the **save.php** file:

```
include("db.php");


$content = $_POST['content']; //get posted data
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);  //escape string 

$sql = "UPDATE content SET text = '$content' WHERE id = '$id' ";

if (mysql_query($sql))
{
    echo 1;
}
```

I know that this could be a stupid question but I am a newbie.

Thank you in advance for the help.

**UPDATE:**
thanx to Luis I fixed my old problem but I don't know why if I put all the code in a while only the "Save" button of the first entry is working good, the rest not, any hint?
At the moment I am testing only "description_text".

Here is the "while" code:

```
<?php 

    /////////// Now let us print the table headers //////////////// 

    $query =" SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY id DESC ";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<div style='width: 100%; text-align: center;'>";                   
    echo "<table style='margin: auto auto;'>";
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Image</th><th>Category</th><th>Description</th><th>Added on</th></tr>";

    while($ordinate = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    $id     = $ordinate['id'];
    $img_name    = $ordinate['img_name'];
    $category     = $ordinate['category'];
    $description_text = $ordinate['description_text'];
    $insert_datetime    = $ordinate['insert_datetime'];

    echo "<tr><td style='width: 20px;'>".$id."</td><td style='width: 210px;'><img src='../../upload/content/uploaded_images/". $img_name ."' width='200px'></td><td style='width: 100px;'>".$category."</td><td style='width: 100px;'><div id='status'></div><div id='content'><div id='editable' contentEditable='true'>".$description_text."</div><button id='save'>Save</button></div></td><td style='width: 100px;'>".$insert_datetime."</td></tr>";        

    }
    echo "</table><br /><br /></div>";
?>
```

Comment: `how can I modify the query to get the ID on the fly` where do you want to get the id from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on index.php move this part of code to the beginning, so you can use same vars in the rest of the script.

```
<?php
    //get data from database.
    include("db.php");
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from content");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);     
    // echo $row['id'];    but keep this ones in its original place inside their <%php %> tags
    // echo "<br />";
    // echo $row['text'];
?>
```

Later in the ajax call, insert this PHP lines:

```
    data: {
    content: content
    <?php
    echo ", id: ".$row['id'];
    echo ", token: '".md5('my SALT text'.(int)$row['id'])."'";    // strongly!!! recomended, not mandatory
    ?>
    },
```

and on save.php

```
    $id = (int)$_POST['id'];                    // (int)  sanitizes  id
    $token = $_POST['token'];
    if(md5('my SALT text'.$id)!=$token) die();  // or whatever but do not execute update
                                                // perhaps  echo 0; die();

    // ... rest of your code ....
    $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = '$content' WHERE id = $id"
```

the token, prevents the risk that someone uses your save.php as a way to inject whatever on every post on the table.

At least, an advice: use mysqli_query (notice the i) instead of mysql_query as this last is deprecated.  Also, but with more diferences, you can use PDO

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. If I do this, the "Save" button does not appear anymore and I cannot save :(

Comment: yes because this answer is not correct ... first `row['id']` is not defined at the point used as ajax param, second no need to change `WHERE id = '$id' "`, third `$id` in `save.php` should be initalized first `$id = $_POST['id'] ` ...

Comment: @Reflective you're right. I was anwsering with half question readed. I am correcting it now. I will also add a token to avoid damage via improper use of ajax calls. but will take a moment.

Comment: @LuisSiquot thank you for the help and for the time you are spending to help me with the code. I will wait for you mod :)

Comment: @LuisSiquot awesome!!! Just one question, just to understand the code in 2 similar line: `echo ", token: '".md5('my SALT text'.(int)$row['id'])."'";` and `if(md5('my SALT text'.$id)!=$token) die();`. What do they do? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: The first one generates a 32 bytes string that acts as a signature over the ID.  The second one, cheks the recived signature ($token var) against the regenerated signature. if both are the same there were no adulteration.  md5 is a **hash** algoritm. on hash algoritms, a single bit change in input generate a totaly unrelated diferent output. So, always add a salt string to be sure that the signature is strong. you can askme again if you need, or google _md5 hash_

Comment: also relevant: hash algoritms, do not have reverse algoritms.

Comment: Now seems correct. Any significant effort should be rewarded!

Comment: @LuisSiquot I have updated my code with another question, I don't know why if I place all the working code in a while, because I generate my table grabbing data from MySQL, it is possible to modify only the first row, not the rest. Any hint? Thank you again

Comment: the working answer (and the original question) are intended to use just one ID.  You should make a new post with this issue.

Comment: you can insert the link of the new question here (on the comments) if you want my attention there

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply echoing the $row['id'], echo it inside an HTML element with specific id, so that it can be accessed from jQuery and  can be posted.

```
<span id="idfield"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></span>
<button id="save">Save</button>
</div>
```

Then, inside the javascript :

```
 $("#save").click(function (e) {         
    var content = $('#editable').html();    
    var id = $('#idfield').html();
```

Use it as a parameter in POST:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'save.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
       content: content,
       id: id
      },
```